# how to extract information I want by NLKT

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-analysis, bigdata

I want to extract relevant information about few topics. for example:

- product information
- purchase experience of customer
- recommendation of family or friend

In first step, I extract information from one of the website. for instance :

> i think AIA does a more better life insurance as my comparison and
>   the companies comparisonand most important is also medical insurance
>   in my opinionyes there are some agents that will sell u plans that
>   their commission is high...dun worry u buy insurance from a company
>   anything happens u can contact back the company also can ...better
>   find a agent that is reliable and not just working for the commission
>   for now , they might not service u in the future...thanksregardsdiana
>   ""

Then by using NLTK in VS2015, I tried to split words.

```
toks = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

By using pos_tag I can tag my toks

```
postoks = nltk.tag.pos_tag(toks)
```

from this part I am not sure what should I do? 
Previously, I used IBM text Analytic. In this software I use to create dictionary and then create some pattern and then analysis the data. for instance
:

> Sample of Dictionary: insurance_cmp : {AIA, IMG, SABB}
>
> Sample of pattern:
>
> insurance_cmp + Good_Feeling_Pattern
>
> insurance_cmp + ['purchase|Buy'] + Bad_Feeling_Pattern
>
> Good_Feeling_Pattern = [good, like it, nice]
>
> Bad_Feeling_Pattern = [bad, worse, not good, regret]

I tried to know can I simulate the same in NLKT? chunker and create grammar can help me to extract what I am looking for? may I have your idea to improve myself please?

```
grammar = r"""
    NBAR:
        {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns

    NP:
        {<NBAR>}
        {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
"""
chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

tree = chunker.parse(postoks)
```

Please help me what could be my next step to reach to my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to follow these [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMyoQbBq5IE&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfRO5bQFLcVgvIOIhNUZpZf&index=1)

or read this [blog](https://pythonprogramming.net/named-entity-recognition-nltk-python/).